# How to filter the 'win_service_info' result in an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-facts

This is my playbook. It shows a service of Windows Server.

```yaml
    - hosts: windows

      tasks:

      - name: Get info all services
        ansible.windows.win_service_info:
           name: Zabbix Agent
        register: service_info

      - debug:
          msg: "{{ service_info }}"
```

But this shows me much results:

```json
  "pre_shutdown_timeout_ms": 180000,
  "preferred_node": null,
  "process_id": 4092,
  "required_privileges": [],
  "service_exit_code": 0,
  "service_flags": [],
  "service_type": "win32_own_process",
  "sid_info": "none",
  "start_mode": "auto",
  "state": "started",
  "triggers": [],
  "username": "\",
  "wait_hint_ms": 0,
  "win32_exit_code": 0
```

Only I need the `start_mode` line.

How can I filter the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That object has [documented properties](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/windows/win_service_info_module.html#return-services/start_mode) that are available as jinja2 expressions:

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: the start_mode of Zabbix is {{ service_info.services[0].start_mode }}
```

Here, because you specified a specific name, the list *should* only have one item in it, but be careful if you change the `_info:` to use a wildcard in the future, as the list may have multiple items

Strictly speaking, it may be that the `services` list has no items if `Zabbix Agent` isn't registered; I don't have a windows instance to confirm what happens in that case

Comment: Awersome! Thank you so much!